# Updating ComboBox List

Tags: c#, list

I am filling a list with comboboxes, which I create dynamically when a button is pressed like this:

```
private void populatePageTwo()
    {
        ComboBox noteBox = new ComboBox();
        noteBox.Location = new Point(50, 15*(comboBoxCount+1)+(20*comboBoxCount));
        noteBox.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        fillNoteComboBox(noteBox);
        comboBoxNoteList.Add(noteBox);

        comboBoxCount++;
    }
```

Later, I have the following check in another thread:

```
Note selectedNote = (Note)this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    selectedNote = (Note)comboBoxNoteList[i].SelectedItem;
                });
```

But I get a `NullReferenceException` and If i check the values in the debugger, the list has items but theyre all null. Do I need to update the list or something?

Comment: Show the code that creates the `comboBoxNoteList`

Comment: List<ComboBox> comboBoxNoteList = new List<ComboBox>();

Comment: What does `fillNoteComboBox();` do?

Comment: it just adds items to the combobox

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler `MethodInvoker` returns `void`, why do you expect it to return some object of `Note`? Secondly, you should set some item as selected in your combobox after populating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because your Invoke call returns null.  From [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

> Return Value 
>   Type: System.Object 
>   The return value from the delegate being invoked, or null if the delegate has no return value.

You can use a Lambda expression, the simplest way for this kind of situation :

```
selectedNote = (Note)Invoke(new Func<Note>(() => (Note)comboBoxNoteList[i].SelectedItem));
```

**EDIT :** The alternative method (yours) is useful when your function takes more than one line.  Here's the syntax :

```
var noteText = (string)Invoke(new Func<String>(delegate 
    { 
        var note = (Note)comboBoxNoteList[i].SelectedItem;
        return note.Text; 
    }));
```

The reason why you're seeing null items with the debugger is probably because the debugger runs in the context of the current thread, which isn't the interface thread, causing a cross-thread issue to return null.

Comment: Gives error: Since 'System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: My bad.  I modified my answer with a syntax that actually works.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you very much! And I also understand now why it didnt work :D Silly me..

Comment: You're welcome.  I also added the correct syntax for the code in your question.